# Como implementar chamadas de voz e vídeo em meus apps

Tags: java, android, sdk

Eu gostaria de saber como posso implementar chamadas de vídeo e de voz (similares às dos Whatsapp) em meus Apps escritos em JAVA para Android. Existe algum SDK open source que facilite isso?

Comment: [Link útil (inglês)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798337/how-to-voice-commands-into-an-android-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é um trabalho nada simples quando se trata de chamadas de audio/video (Tanto é que depois de muito tempo o WhatsApp implementou chamadas de vídeo). Você pode procurar mais sobre [protocolo SIP no android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) que está disponível no Android a partir da API nível 9.

Uma exemplo de chamada seria este trecho que define a ação `android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL`, que será usada por um filtro de intenções quando o dispositivo receber uma chamada. Veja:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
```

No entanto, existem sim alguma plataformas *open sourcing* que poderia muito bem te ajudar com esses recursos. Seria interessante analisar cada um tomar uma decisão do qual se encaixa melhor as suas necessidades.

- [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/)
- [Telegram](https://telegram.org/)
- [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/)
- [Doubango](http://www.doubango.org/)
- [Whisper Systems](https://whispersystems.org/)

Leia mais sobre o protocolo SIP na própria [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html).